# Analog of Baker's theorem on linear combination of $\log a \log b$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Baker's theorem basically says that, given algebraic numbers $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ and $m_1,\ldots,m_n$, if there is no good reason for a linear combination

$$\sum m_i\log a_i$$

to cancel, then it is nonzero and has a lower bound, roughly $O(H)$, where $H$ is the height of $m_i$.

I wonder if there is a version like the following: given algebraic numbers $a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_n$ and integers $m_1,\ldots,m_n$, what can we say about a linear combination

$$\sum m_i\log a_i\log b_i$$

(preferably, a quantitative version of the lower bound).

Comment: Is it even known that $\log2\log3$ is irrational?

Comment: Schanuel's conjecture implies that the logarithms of the primes are algebraically independent. I have no idea what's known unconditionally.